# Django deltatime with the largest unit

Tags: django, django-templates, python-datetime, python-3.6

I'm try to create a render for any objects `Album`, i get the last `picture` added and i would like to compare with `now` (the date for pictures is in `picture.date`).

**But in my render i when the largest unit of time**.

*models:*

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

class Album(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField( max_length=50)
     ...

class Pictures(models.Model):
     album = models.ForeignKey(Album,
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                         related_name='albums')
    date = models.DateTimeField( default=now)
    ...
```

In the *template* i create a timeline of album, i use a loop :

```
{% for a in album %}
    related album : {{ a.name }}
    last modif was {{ a.pictures.last.date }} ago.
{% endfor %}
```

For example the render will be something like:

```
5s
1min
2h
3days
```

So if i have `datetime.timedelta(0, 5, 279122)` just return **5 s**, or if i have `datetime.timedelta( 01 , 25, 279122)` just return **1 day**.

So i try to find an operation between `now` and `picture.date`, something like truncated `datetime.timedelta` for is bigger unit is possible ? I don't want panoply of `if` conditions.

Comment: Note that `timedelta(1 , 25, 279122)` is "1 **day**, 25 seconds, 279122 microseconds", not "1 min" as your question suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`naturaltime`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime) template filter.

First, you need to add `'django.contrib.humanize'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting, and then in your template, you can do:

```
{% load humanize %}
{{ a.pictures.last.date|naturaltime }}
```

If that doesn't do what you want, then you could write your own [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/). This would keep the logic out of the template.

There is also a [`timesince`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince) filter. However 'minutes' is the smallest unit it handles, so it is not useful if you want to display "5 seconds ago".

Comment: I totaly miss out on `django.contrib.humanize`, and write filter isn't optimize like django methode.